# Should I use ANOVA or MANOVA for this repeated measures experiment?

Tags: repeated-measures, missing-data, degrees-of-freedom

**I would like to test for the difference of measures between genders. Repeated measures were carried out. What test would you suggest is best for this and what would be the degrees of freedom considering:**

> > > 1. there is no change in conditions
> > > 2. uneven group size (females=6 and males=4)
> > > 3. missing repeated measures (8 levels) between 3 subjects**

### The Data Explained

There are *6 females* and *4 males* = **10 subjects in total**

*28 Repeated measures* (events or levels) per person with **no** change in condition except time.

> 28 x 10 subjects = **280 repeated measures (rm)**

At each level there should be:

> *19 ordinal independent variables* **(IV)**
>
> > **from** which
>
> *7 continuous dependent variables* **(DV)** are recorded
>
> > 19 (IV) x 7 (DV) =  133 measures (one level per subject)
> > 133 x 28 rm per subject = 3724 measures (all levels per subject)
> > 3724 x 10 subjects  = 37240 total measures of data

#### Missing data (from the expected totals as described above)

> *8 levels* of data between *3 subjects* are missing:
>
> > **2 events** (rm) missing for **2 males** 
> > **4 events** (rm) missing for **1 female**
> > 280 rm - 8 rm  = **272 rm in total**
> > 8 missing rm x 133 measures per rm = **1064 total measures missing** 
> > 37240 - 1064 = **36176 total measures of data**

Comment: It might be best to use a mixed model, using subject as the random effect with the rest as fixed effects. Repeated measures ANOVA is not going to work with missing values (you would have to exclude subjects list-wise). Can you give the specific example of the data you are working with? What are the 7 DVs? Do they use the same units (on the same scale)?

Comment: @KayleSawyer Thanks :) What do you mean subject list-wise. Do you mean i have to remove 3 of those subjects with missing data for the entire analyses? Yes these 7 DVs have the same unit on the same scale

Comment: You need to give more information if you want a good answer. Can you describe each variable, and give a sample of your data or show a similar dataset? You can read this to get an idea of what you need to provide for a good question (and feel free to edit your question): https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Comment: @KayleSawyer Thanks for helping as much as you can on this.

Comment: @KayleSawyer - yes indeed, edited edited edited. It is a challenging one no doubt.